# Latexmkrc to compile several subprojects in a project

Tags: latexmk, overleaf

We have a project, which consists of several independent documents:

```
- 01-vision
  - vision.tex
- 02-presentation-1
  - presentation-1.tex
```

which we would like to compile with `Latexmk`.

"We" are two persons. I can compile these documents just by `cd`ing to the
corresponding subfolder because I work locally using Visual Studio Code editor.

However, my partner works on Overleaf platform, which does not goes to the
subfolders. However, you can control Overleaf through `latexmkrc` file
as they use `latexmk` for building.

How to right Overleaf-compatible `latexmkrc` such that it changes to a subfolder and then compiles `tex`-documents there?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) In Overleaf, you can set the main document for the project, which is the file that's compiled when first opening the project or if another .tex file is opened. However, to facilitate compiling multiple documents within a project, when you press the Compile button, if the file you have open in Overleaf contains a `\documentclass` line, it will be compiled regardless of the main file you've set. What parts of the `latexmkrc` you use on your local TeX distribution are not working in Overleaf?

Comment: The idea is that latexmk goes to the subdirectory and compiles from there. Otherwise it cannot find images and bibtex file in the subfolder. I can solve the image problem via graphics path macro, but it still cannot find bibtex file.

Comment: Right, but do you have an example you can share? It's difficult to help without knowing exactly what approach you're using locally. This is specific enough that it may be better to contact us at support@overleaf.com, though if we're working from a generic enough example it may be interesting/useful to the broader community too.

Comment: I experimented today with Overleaf myself. It turned out that Overleaf works as expected: it cd's into the document subfolder, I guess, as the compilation happens correctly (images in the subfolder and a bibtex file are found all right). The issue is then only on my local machine with the environment I use (vscode).

Comment: `Latexmk` has an option to change to the directory of a document, and compile it there.  On the command line this is done with the option `-cd`.  To set this behavior from a `latexmkrc` file, use `$do_cd=1;`.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @JohnCollins, yes, thank you! This is the option I use now locally, and there is no need to use latexmkrc file.